# Why did Neji’s father stil have the Hyuga curse mark on his forehead even after his death?

Tags: naruto

When Neji dies in *Naruto Shippuden* episode 365, his Hyuga curse mark disappeared from his forehead.

However, why does his father still have it on his head which was reanimated?

Answer (score 1):

The Cursed Mark of the Hyuga Branch family has two purposes:

1. To allow the Main family to easily put under control a rebellious
   member.
2. To ensure that, if they die in battle, their Byakugan will
   not be stolen.

Now, Edo Hizashi seems to still have the Byakugan in his power(although he doesn’t actually use it), so it makes sense that the Curse Mark is still present to make sure that it cannot be stolen. What does not make complete sense is why he still has the Byakugan, although when it comes to Orochimaru and his experiments very little surprises me at this point.

[image]

Here is Neji’s forehead as he is dying, which shows that the seal is indeed erased during death.
Below is Edo Hizashi, with his Seal and apparent Byakugan.

[image]

Another theory is that Hizashi wasn’t killed in a traditional way, and was instead sealed somewhere in order to steal his Byakugan, and for some reason the Curse Mark didn’t detect this as death and so it didn’t deactivate. Or honestly it might have just been a mistake. Who knows...

Answer (score 0):

**It was activated.**

I‘m not sure, but in my opinion it could be, because it was activated. The mark can be activated by any member of the main family as a punishment and the person wearing it will suffer from pain. Nejis mark was, as far as i know, never activated, his fathers was. (I don‘t know whih episode, you can see it as a memory from Neji at the jounin-exam)

My theory is, that it‘s only visible after death, when it was activated and burned itself in the forehead.

Maybe i‘m completely wrong and it‘s just a mistake by the editors.

Comment: Please include relevant sources/references.

Comment: Nejis curse mark was actually activated, there was a time when he was training hinata and subconsciously went too hard in attacking. That led to Hiashi punishing him https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RAWZlOrqZGQ